# Apply background color to each cell of Pandas dataframe by taking reference value from another cell of same row in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to set background color to each cell in Pandas dataframe.

For example:
1st row colA = 30% (20%) and reference value is 40%. First, I extract the value to be compared from colA i.e. 30%, after removing value in bracket. This value will be compared against reference value of 40%. The background color of cell is Green when reference value is greater.

2nd row colA - 25% < 30% therefore, color will be green

I am able to do this when the reference value is common for all the rows by applying style elementwise but unable to do so for different reference values for different rows.

Can anyone help here ?

Attaching dataframe code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Reference': ['40%','30%'],
                  'colA': ['30% (20%)','25% (14%)'],
                  'colB': ['45% (20%)','25% (30%)'],
                  'colC': ['25% (30%)','35% (30%)']})
```

Required Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can [`appyly`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) a custom styler to a DataFrame.

```
def highlight(x, color1, color2):
    ref = x[0]
    ans = [None]
    for y in x[1:]:
        c = color1 if y < ref else color2
        ans.append(f"color: {c};")
    return ans

df.style.apply(highlight, color1='green', color2='red', axis=1)
```

[image: color changed]

If you want to set the background color, use `f"background-color: {c};"` in your custom function.

[image: background color changed]